# OutofMemoryException - Loading Extremely Large Images

Tags: c#, large-files, out-of-memory

I'm trying to load an extremely large image (14473x25684), but I'm hitting into a memory limitation.

Here's a simple program to demonstrate the problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string largeimage = @"C:\Temp\test_image.jpg"; // 14473x25684

    Image i = Bitmap.FromFile(largeimage); // OutofMemoryException was unhandled
}
```

Now I understand that the issue isn't relevant to how much physical memory I have, but rather is an addressing limitation. Is there anything I can do to get around this limitation?

The image is indeed valid and it opens fine in Photoshop (VM Size: 916MB) and ACDSee.
Also don't bother to Google the dimensions as the dimensions listed aren't exact. :)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I've run into this before. From what I can tell it's the framework kicking over.

Comment: Wow. That's a big picture. Unfortunately, the framework Bitmap class won't cover your needs. You may find that taking a chunked approach, where you marshal the bitmap header yourself and sample the pixels into a more manageable image dimension is your best bet. It's a challenge though, as it involves a little wheel-rebuilding. I'd be surprised if Photoshop and ACDSee load the entire uncompressed image into memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bitmap class will require around 1.5GB of memory to hold that instance. The .NET memory allocator normally chokes around the 1GB mark.

Answer (score 0):

OS can not allocate contiguous amount of memory. All you can do about that is use of [MemoryFailPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx) and catch InsufficientMemoryException.
But this only save you from app crashing.
As for me, to open such a big file you should use binary reader and draw a file via System.Drawing.

here is good question and answers [When is it OK to catch an OutOfMemoryException and how to handle it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117142/when-is-it-ok-to-catch-an-outofmemoryexception-and-how-to-handle-it)

Comment: The OS can do it (if it's a 64-bit OS), but the .NET framework can't (even if it's 64 bits).